# How to sum-up values of a column A, with same ID in column B in QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, summarizing, column

In my QGIS, I have a shape file that already contains a column stating the size of each urban green space and a column that holds the area ID (equal to a zip code).

Via the field calculator, I would now like to create a new column in which all the urban green space areas are added up that have the same area ID/zip code, so that I can see how many square meters of urban green space is available for each zip code.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the [`sum()`-function](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=sum#sum)?

Comment: @Erik I suppose so..? The catch is that only values (from column A) should be summed-up, that have the exact same area ID (from column B) and I don't know how to factor in this condition.

Comment: Have you have a look at the link I posted? If so, what is left unclear?

Comment: I did, thank you! I have to double check but it might've just been
sum("Size_each",group_by:="PLR_ID") for me.

Comment: Sounds about correct.